# How can I send g-code commands to a pcb printer through Pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

I been trying to send simple g-code commands to a Voltera V-One printer by Pyserial.  The printer connects to my Windows PC through port "COM3" and the baudrate is at 250000.  I tried the simple examples on the Pyserial documentation page: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-port. I have not been successful.  [Attached is the image of the errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTTA9.png)

Thank you

Comment: Code and errors should be posted in the question, not in images.

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/ttyUSB0` would be a name of a serial port on a Linux system. On Win, you need to use simply 'COM3'